# Can't close C++ Console Application without R6010?

Tags: c++, delay, sleep, exit

I decided to take the plunge in C++ after using Python for a couple of years now. Right now, I am trying to make a program that flashes LEDs on my keyboard every 60 minutes to remind me to stretch using their keyboard SDK. The flashing and timing work, but the problem is closing the program when you don't want or need it open.

I can exit the program before I first call the `alarm()` function. After I call the that `alarm` function, I get the Windows pop saying that I can either Abort, ignore, or retry with the code R6010.

I currently have it setup to try to catch a Ctrl-C event and end the while loop, but that ends with the same error anyways.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "SDKDLL.h"
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::this_thread; 
using namespace std::chrono;
BYTE r = 0;
BYTE g = 0;
BYTE b = 0;
bool exiter = false;//Exit variable
void my_handler(int s){// Tells me when CTRL C was pressed
    printf("Caught signal %d\n", s);
    ::exiter = true;

}
void alarm(){
    //Basically turns on and off LEDs 5 times
    for (int x = 1; x < 5; x++){

        Sleep(500);
        r = 255;
        g = 255;
        b = 255;
        SetFullLedColor(r, g, b);
        Sleep(500);
        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 0;
        SetFullLedColor(r, g, b);
    }

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    signal(SIGINT, my_handler);//Trying to find a way for the program to exit nicely, this way uses CTRL C
    SetControlDevice(DEV_MKeys_M_White);

    while (::exiter == false){
        sleep_until(system_clock::now() + seconds(4));//waits X seconds to do the sequence again
        EnableLedControl(true);//Allows for control of LED
        alarm();//Turns off and on the LEDS
        EnableLedControl(false);//Disables the LEDs
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I have been researching this error for a couple hours with no solution working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to explore other ways to accomplish your goal. ``signal()`` is a rather unix-ish way of tackling this problem. See for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685049(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @BitTickler I used that method in your link and it worked! You should post that as an answer so you can get the credit you deserve!